# How to do a design sprint test with a logo

Tags: logo, client-relations

I'm a product designer who practices design sprints the best I can.

To summarize [design sprints](https://www.gv.com/sprint/), in a week you choose the questions about your product to focus on, you try to find solutions, you prototype several ones and at the end of the week, **you ask a real end user to use a prototype** in front of you and you see if it works.

What I find really interesting in the [prototype user testing process](https://library.gv.com/the-gv-research-sprint-interview-participants-and-summarize-findings-day-4-3d34792baa3f) is that you don't ask people "do you find this static image of an app interface well designed ?" but **you just watch them** use it and see if it's the right solution or not. **It's factual**, not based on tastes or opinions.

I'm currently working on a logo for an app and I'd like to reproduce this process. I have several ideas and propositions and I'd like to find a process to get genuine insights about:

- Does the font match the core business of the app?
- Are the colors in line with the image we want to give?
- Are each proposition readable and still have a personality?

I could ask friends and users "which logo do you prefer ?" or "which one is the best for the app according to you ?" but that would express personal tastes and will not **test if it matches the unconscious meaning of colors, fonts, shapes** that makes our brain link a logo to an industry or to a specific target.

I have an idea of a process which is showing 15 logos (some fictive, some reals) and ask people to link the logos with the industry the brand is operating in. It would give me insights about how many people linked my logos to the right industry.

But that's just an idea, and I'm sure there is some reliable process that professionals use to make a factual choice.

Comment: What you described of having them categorize the logo doesn't feel like a design sprint at all given it's not in any sort of prototype. I think design-sprinting a logo is the wrong approach, not everything can be solved using the same technique